Making thin wars with provided jar-of-jars
On our Tomcats we run multiple wars, with the same version of the war, but different tenant-specific configurations, as parts of are application suite are not yet multi-tenant. To speed up war deployment, we thought of the following approach:

Create a jar-of-jars and store it in $CATALINA_OUT/lib, which basically contains all jars of the application.
Deploy multiple thin wars, using that shared jar-of-jars.

Is this approach possible, and does it have (dis)advantages compared to deployment of fat wars?

Web Project
multi-tenant
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── TenantServlet.java
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

pom.xml
dependency setting <scope>provided</scope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-tenant</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>multi-tenant</name>
    <description>Jakarta EE 10 Hello Web</description>
    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>multi-tenant</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

TenantServlet.java
Servlet to test whether multi-tenant settings are in effect.
package com.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Properties;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TenantServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Properties tenantConfig;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        //Read the tenant's configuration file path from the Context
        String configFilePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("configFile");
        System.out.println("configFilePath = " + configFilePath);
        System.out.println("ContextPath = "+getServletContext().getContextPath());

        tenantConfig = new Properties();
        
        try {
            //InputStream is1 =  getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(configFilePath);
            InputStream is1=new FileInputStream(configFilePath);
            if (is1==null){
                System.out.println("is1 == null");
            }
            tenantConfig.load(is1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Failed to load tenant configuration", e);
        }

        //Initialize JNDI resources
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            String dsString = "java:comp/env/jdbc/" + tenantConfig.getProperty("dbName");
            System.out.println("dsString = " +  dsString);
            dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(dsString);
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            //Create Statement
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
            // Check if there is a result
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("MySQL connection test successful: " + resultSet.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Failed to lookup DataSource", e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to SQLException",e);
        } finally {
            // Close the resource
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if (statement != null) statement.close();
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Use tenant configuration
        String welcomeMessage = tenantConfig.getProperty("welcomeMessage");
        resp.getWriter().write(welcomeMessage);
    }
}

web.xml
Set the URL of TenantServlet to /hellotenant
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>MultiTenantWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TenantServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TenantServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.TenantServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TenantServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hellotenant</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>

Build
mvn clean package


Output : target/multi-tenant.war

Tomcat Server Config

apache-tomcat-10.1.28
JDK 17

apache-tomcat-10.1.28
├── conf
│   ├── Catalina
│   │   └── localhost
│   │       ├── tenant1.xml
│   │       └── tenant2.xml
│   └── catalina.properties
├── ext-webapps
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── tenant1-config.properties
│   │   └── tenant2-config.properties
│   └── multi-tenant.war
└── shared
    └── multi-tenant-lib
        ├── mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar
        └── protobuf-java-3.25.1.jar

Shared Lib Jar
For this example:

in tomcat folder ,

mkdir -p shared/multi-tenant-lib


move all dependency jar into apache-tomcat-10.1.28/shared/multi-tenant-lib

ext-webapps

in tomcat folder ,

mkdir ext-webapps

apache-tomcat-10.1.28/ext-webapps
├── conf
│   ├── tenant1-config.properties
│   └── tenant2-config.properties
└── multi-tenant.war


tenant1-config.properties (for your tenant1 config)
tenant2-config.properties (for your tenant2 config)
multi-tenant.war (copy from target/multi-tenant.war)

tenant1-config.properties
dbName=tenant1db
welcomeMessage=Welcome, Tenant 1!

tenant2-config.properties
dbName=tenant2db
welcomeMessage=Welcome, Tenant 2!

config
apache-tomcat-10.1.28/conf
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
│       ├── tenant1.xml
│       └── tenant2.xml
└── catalina.properties

Create tenant config

in apache-tomcat-10.1.28/conf

mkdir -p Catalina/localhost

tenant1.xml
<!-- Tenant 1 Context -->
<Context path="/tenant1" docBase="../ext-webapps/multi-tenant.war" reloadable="true">
            
    <!-- external configuration file -->
    <Parameter name="configFile" value="../ext-webapps/conf/tenant1-config.properties" override="false"/>
    
    <!-- JNDI resource configuration -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/tenant1db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant1"
              username="tenant1user" password="tenant1password"/>
</Context>

tenant2.xml
<!-- Tenant 2 Context -->
<Context path="/tenant2" docBase="../ext-webapps/multi-tenant.war" reloadable="true">

    <!-- external configuration file -->
    <Parameter name="configFile" value="../ext-webapps/conf/tenant2-config.properties" override="false"/>
    <!-- JNDI resource configuration -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/tenant2db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant2"
              username="tenant2user" password="tenant2password"/>
</Context>

catalina.properties
Find shared.loader= and modify it to the following:
shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/multi-tenant-lib/*.jar

Test
Start Tomcat

in Tomcat/bin

./startup.sh

Tests
Test1
http://localhost:8080/tenant1/hellotenant

show: Welcome, Tenant 1!
welcomeMessage from apache-tomcat-10.1.28/ext-webapps/conf/tenant1-config.properties , welcomeMessage=Welcome, Tenant 1!
Test2
http://localhost:8080/tenant2/hellotenant

show: Welcome, Tenant 2!
welcomeMessage from apache-tomcat-10.1.28/ext-webapps/conf/tenant2-config.properties , welcomeMessage=Welcome, Tenant 2!
Check Tomcat webapps
Tomcat created tenant1 and tenant2 in webapps from our ext-webapps/multi-tenant.war.
apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps
├── tenant1
└── tenant2

Conclusion
The above settings meet the following requirements:

Use a war file
Set up different configuration files for different tenants
Extract the jar file used by war and turn it into a shared jar directory. Make the war smaller.

Appendix: Test database settings
init.sql
-- Create database
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS demodb;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS tenant1;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS tenant2;

-- Create users and grant permissions
CREATE USER 'demouser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rd!';
CREATE USER 'tenant1user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tenant1password';
CREATE USER 'tenant2user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tenant2password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON demodb.* TO 'demouser'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tenant1.* TO 'tenant1user'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tenant2.* TO 'tenant2user'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Use the Docker command to start the test database.
docker run --name my-mysql-2 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Passw0rd! \
  -v `pwd`/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -d mysql:latest


Database account and password

Database    User        Password
----        ----        ----
X       root        Passw0rd!
demodb      demouser    Passw0rd!
tenant1     tenant1user tenant1password
tenant2     tenant2user tenant2password

